# Optimizing for more than one argument in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, fminsearch

Consider the following Matlab function

```
function [f, dfx1, dfx2] = optifun(x1,x2)
f = x1(1)^2 + x1(2)^2 + x2^2;

% Gradients
dfx1(1) = 2*x1(1);
dfx1(2) = 2*x1(2);
dfx2    = 2*x2;
```

My objective is to optimize the above function with respect to `x1` and `x2`  using function `fminunc, which also incorporates gradients. I do not know whether it is possible to optimize the function if it's defined in above fashion.

My approach would be(but I know that it won't work):

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon', 'SpecifyObjectiveGradient',true);
% Initializing 
x10 = [1, 1];
x20 = 1;

[t1, t2] = fminunc(@(x1, x2)optifun(x1,x2), x10, x20, options);
```

Edits: I have made corrections as pointed out by user:@m7913d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Main problem**

Your function signature does not correspond with the expectations of [`fminunc`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html): you can only specify one (initial) `x` vector and one gradient vector, which should contain all the variables/gradients. If you do not want to `optifun` (which is the preferred solution), you can define a helper function as follows:

```
function [f, df] = optifun_helper(x)
  [f, dfx1, dfx2] = optifun(x(1:2),x(3));
  df = [dfx1 dfx2];
end
```

And use this function to solve your optimisation problem:

```
[x] = fminunc(@(x) optifun_helper(x), [x10 x20], options);
```

**Minor issues**

There are other problems with your code. The first error I get is:

```
Error using optimoptions (line 118)
Invalid solver specified. Provide a solver name or handle (such as 'fmincon' or @fminunc).
Type DOC OPTIMOPTIONS for a list of solvers.
```

As the error message suggested, you should specify your solver as the first argument:

```
options = optimoptions('fminunc','SpecifyObjectiveGradient',true);
```

The second problem is that some output variables of `optifun` are never defined due to spelling issue (you define `df1` instead of `dfx1`):

```
function [f, dfx1, dfx2] = optifun(x1,x2)
  f = x1(1)^2 + x1(2)^2 + x2^2;

  % Gradients
  dfx1(1) = 2*x1(1);
  dfx1(2) = 2*x1(2);
  dfx2    = 2*x2;
end
```

*As a conclusion, always read the error messages and documentation carefully and try to fit your code in the expected syntax.*

Comment: @pkj Please take a look at your previous questions and check if you do not need to accept the given answers.

Comment: My sincere apologies for posting an erroneous and incomplete question. The problem I am working on was lengthy to post, so I posted a synthetic problem and did not bothered to recheck it. You have addressed my real doubt as last clarification. I had a function which is accessed by many scripts and I wanted some way to work around with it without changing the structure of the function; seems like there is no way. Your helper function will do the work. Thank you for answering the question and sorry that my ill-formated question wasted your time. I will look at my previous questions.